# Using Chrome flags with QtWebEngine (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, chromium, qtwebengine, google-chrome-flags

For the development of my PyQt5 browser project, I read [here](https://myprogrammingnotes.com/pass-parameters-chromium-qtwebengine.html) that by passing Chrome flags as application arguments, they will automatically be passed onto the `QtWebEngineProcess.exe` when it gets launched by the code. I have tried doing `app = QApplication(sys.argv + [--enable-force-dark])`, but this doesn't make the chromium render the web pages in dark mode (I have also tries lots of variations of the flag name, so I assume this isn't the problem).

I am wondering whether it is possible to manually call the `QtWebEngineProcess.exe` with custom flags set, from the PyQt5 code by inheriting a class and overriding a function, and connecting the `QtWebEngineView` to this class, so like `...("QtWebEngineProcess.exe -[1st flag] -[2nd flag"])`?

If the above method is not possible, is there any other way to use chromium with custom flags in the `QtWebEngineView`? I am running `PyQt5.14.2 (Chromium 77), Python 3.8.0, Windows 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the chromium flags can be done using the following methods(See [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-debugging.html#using-command-line-arguments)):

- Pass as arguments to QApplication:

  ```py
  args = ["--foo-arg=foo-value", "--bar-arg=bar-value"]
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)
  # or 
  # app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv + args)
  ```
- Set it through the environment variable `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS`:

  ```py
  import os

  os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--foo-arg=foo-value --bar-arg=bar-value"
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ```

And therefore your attempt is correct but the problem seems to be that not all chromium flags are supported by Qt WebEngine and that seems to be the case for `--enable-force-dark`. Searching the net I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/f2plcs/dark_mode_in_qt_webengine_browsers_eg_falkon_with/) that provides an alternative: `--blink-settings=darkMode=4,darkModeImagePolicy=2`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    os.environ[
        "QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"
    ] = "--blink-settings=darkMode=4,darkModeImagePolicy=2"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # or
    # args = sys.argv + ["--blink-settings=darkMode=4,darkModeImagePolicy=2"]
    # app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv + args)

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]