# PyQt5 Web Engine Google Sign in

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I'm creating a browser using the PyQt5 Web Engine, however when I try to sign in via google, I'm getting the following message:
[image: The error I'm getting]

I've tried many of the solutions on StackOverflow, including [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816703/using-chrome-flags-with-qtwebengine-pyqt5) however they aren't making a difference.

The code I'm currently running (excluding functions and classes):

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("Browser")

window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Please tell me what I may be doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just managed to find a solution, under where I had `browser = QWebEngineView()`, I put in an User agent:

```
browser.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
        )
```

This worked for me, though it took a lot of research